# javax.persistence dose not exist but installed in maven

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I didn't get an answer when I googled it.

Currently, JDK is using 1.8. JPA Plugin is also installed.

I want to use Persistence, but I can't currently use it with the following error.

(but  It is really questionable why importing is possible.)

As a result of Googling, many of the answers were maven refresh, etc.

This didn't work for me.

waiting for your answer.

Thank you very much!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using JDK and not JRE. Enter File > Project Structure > SDKs.
Also try to add this dependency from the link:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api/2.2